# Is there a neural network architecture specialized for mapping lower-to-higher-dimensional data?

Tags: neural-networks, feedforward-neural-networks, training-datasets

I am building a neural network that takes in a set of 86 parameters (primarily architecture-related, such as building floor area, kitchen size, number of a certain type of furniture, etc.) and outputs a 4D mulitdimensional array of shape `(6, 2532, 39, 5)` containing vertices of path data that are meant to output to a CAD file of the building. As of the current moment, I am using the most primitive method to do this: a basic densely-connected neural network with the architecture:

```
Input(86),
Normalize(),
Dense(64, activation="relu"),
Dense(128, activation="relu"),
Dense(128, activation="relu"),
# required for the reshape
Dense(2962440),
Reshape((6, 2532, 39, 5))
```

However, this densely-connected neural network produces losses in the trillions, making it hardly viable as a deployable model. This is to be expected - MLPs aren't meant to map lower-dimensional features onto higher-dimensional labels. My "cheating" way of making a `Dense` layer of high enough dimensions to do a reshape isn't truly providing information that the neural network can use to learn. Yet I cannot think of a neural network architecture specialized for low-to-high dimensional training - most architectures are instead specialized for high-to-low dimensional training, like CNNs, which reduce 2D/3D data down to 1D.

Is there any neural network architecture suitable for the task I have outlined?

---

UPDATE: I found that significant loss reduction could be accomplished by rescaling my train labels to between [0, 1]. However, the model now performs poorly on any input data other than its own training dataset, as the rescaling means that the neural network is highly sensitive to any variation in input data.

Comment: probably can take inspiration from GAN encoders